# Viddler webcam recording

Tags: javascript, api, webcam

How to perform an action after webcam recording complete and saved. Viddler webcam recording javascript API. Is there any onsave event. Please let me know with example.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Docuemntation of Viddler api there is nice documention on developer site..

**Recorder JavaScript API**

**CONTROLLING THE RECORDER**

The webcam controller can be controlled using the following JavaScript functions:

***doStartRecord()***

> start the recording

***doStopRecord()***

> stop recording

***doDelRecord()***

> delete recorded footage

***doSaveRecord()***

> save the footage

**CALLBACKS**

***recordConnected()***

> when recorder swf connects to the recording service.

**recordAuthorised()**

> > when recorder swf authorises it’s record token
>
> successfully.

**streamAccessDenied()**

> when a user denies Flash access to the camera and Microphone (by
>   clicking “Deny” at the Flash prompt.)

**streamAccessAllowed()**

> when a user allows Flash access to the camera and Microphone (by
>   clicking “Allow” at the Flash prompt.)

**recordStarted()**

> when user starts recording.

**recordStopped()**

> when user stops recording.

**recordBuffering(percent)**

> when the preview beings to buffer before playback

.

**recordBufferFull()**

> when the recorded video buffer is complete and begins preview
>   playback.

**recordFlushed()**

> when the recorder flushes the record buffer. After this callback, you
>   can call the doDelRecord() or doSaveRecord() functions.

**recordDeleted()**

> when user decides to delete the footage and re-record.

**recordSave()**

> when user decides to save video (yet before the request is sent to the
>   server for actual processing).

**recordDone(username, videoNum, videoKey)** –

> when a video is successfully registered with backend systems and
>   accessible on the site, Passes along the Viddler username, video
>   number and video key back.

Look at this [Link](http://developers.viddler.com/?javascript#recorder-javascript-api)

Comment: I have gone through viddler documentation but i could not understand how to use javascript api with these functions. Would you please give me a example code of viddler javascript api where these functions have been used ?